# Launching a program via `xdg-open` from a subshell without blocking

Tags: terminal, process, zsh, subshell, xdg-open

I've noticed that calling `xdg-open` from a subshell will reliably block until the launched process is closed.  I suspect there may be a reason for this, but I'm not sure as to why.  For example, launching Nautilus doesn't block when calling `xdg-open` directly from the command line:

```
xdg-open ~/dir ; echo foo              # doesn't block
```

but invoking xdg-open from a subshell will reliably block the terminal

```
var=$(xdg-open ~/dir ; echo foo)       # blocks

{ xdg-open ~/dir ; echo foo ; } | cat  # blocks.
```

My understanding is that `xdg-open` detaches the launched process from the shell session so that it's no longer a subprocess.  I'd therefore expect this to be different to e.g. invoking `sleep 1 &` in a subshell for which it seems reasonable that the terminating subshell will block until all subprocess have completed, i.e.

```
var=$(sleep 1 & echo foo)      # also blocks, but understandable.
```

But if `xdg-open` is detaching the process, what's causing the subshell to wait?

In what may (?) be a partial answer, I've noticed that running

```
{ xdg-open <file> ; ps ; } | cat
```

shows that depending on program launched by `<file>`, those that block are also the ones that keep the tty as their controlling terminal.  That begs the question why this happens, why this happens only in a subshell and ultimately what's a good way to a launch desktop process from the terminal that will fully and reliably detach from it?

Edit: fix syntax on `bash`.

Comment: Which shell are you using? If `bash`, note that subshells are started with `(...)`.

Comment: I'm using `zsh`, but I observe the same with `bash`.  Note the use of `{...}` was to simplify the example - the output is piped to `cat` so my understanding is it is still invoked in a subshell. You get the same behavior in `bash` if you wrap in a function from which you pipe the output.

Comment: Ok, but, what is it you're trying to do? `xdg-open` will end up calling the appropriate application, so your results may vary, they may even depend on whether there's already an open window for that application or not...

Comment: I'm trying to launch a program via `xdg-open` from a subshell without blocking the shell that invokes `xdg-open`.  When `xdg-open` is invoked outside of a subshell the shell doesn't block - I would like to do this reliably in both cases, and better understand why there's a difference.

Comment: An ampersand at the end of the command is not enough? `xdg-open ... &`

Comment: Afraid not, for the same reason `sleep 1 &` in the question isn't.  I need to understand what else is in play here.

Comment: Please `export XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=4` and try again, and post the debug logs. And tell us what OS/distribution/version and what desktop environment you're running. Is Nautilus already running? For me, `xdg-open .` opens a Nautilus window; if Nautilus is already running the window is opened in the existing process and `xdg-open` returns immediately, whereas if Nautilus is not running `xdg-open` blocks until I kill `nautilus` manually, at which point `xdg-open` opens a Thunar window and returns immediately.

Comment: More testing and it's evident that it's not consistent - the shell has quirks, so I thought it might be a thing.  Arch/Xorg/Gnome 3.38 with `xdg-open .` set to open in Nautilus, but the same occurs with Thunar or other apps, notably when an instance of the app isn't already running.  If an instance is running `xdg-open` doesn't block even in a subshell and and then also when invoked inside a subshell for a few minutes afterwards (rather haphazardly). Setting `export XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=4` just reports one line "Selected DE gnome3". Note `xdg-open` never blocks outside of a subshell.

Comment: My original thought was that this was a shell/process thing I was missing, but now I understand it's more likely to be a quirk of `xdg-open` or my system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your examples,

```
var=$(sleep 1 & ; echo foo)
```

should not work in `bash`, because `&` already serves as a line end.
(-bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `;')

Try

```
var=$(sleep 1 & echo foo) # no ';' !!
```

(echo $var: foo)

In my understanding, a simple

```
xdg-open <something> & # optional: echo foo
```

should do the trick, either in a sub-shell or outside.

Comment: You're right - I checked in `bash` and the example fails.  I was doing this in `zsh` which seems more forgiving, but your approach is portable and probably correct regardless.  But I think the use of `&` here is a distraction, since running a command in the background (of the subshell) is still insufficient since I assume the parent process must still wait for the child (subshell) to fully complete before execution of the parent can progress.  But `xdg-open` should fully detach the launched process and complete? Perhaps it's a just a quirk of `xdg-open` or something I'm not considering.

Comment: @wardw You can also try starting xdg-open without '&', then go back to the terminal, press `Ctrl+Z` and type `bg X` (Replace X with the number from the prompt, e.g. [X]+ Stopped   xdc-open <something>). That should manually send it to background and finish detached from your active terminal.